# Conditional probability computation

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am having a hard time understanding something that supposedly should be very simple. I have a random variable $X$, taking values in the set of integers $\{0,1,\ldots,11\}$ and is uniformly distributed in this set.
I also have a function $f(X)$ that given a realization of $X$, $x$ gives in output the binary representation of $x$ if $0\leq x \leq 7$ of $x-8$ otherwise.

Then it says that "clearly"
$$ P(x:f(x)=y| |y|=3)= \frac{1/12}{8/12} = 1/8$$

Of course, the $P(|y|=3)= 8/12$ as it corresponds to the probability of $x\in\{0,1,\ldots,7\}$. But the numerator confuses me: why is $P(i:f(x)=y \land|y|=3)$ still $1/12$?

Thank you for any suggestion you will provide me.

Comment: Is there a typo at $...f(x)=y||y|=3...$? And how does your $f(x)$ look like?

Comment: Not a typo, it's the notation used in the notes : probability of y=f(x) conditioned on the length of y being fixed to 3. The function is described above: given a value x it outputs the binary representation in three bits if x is smaller or equal to 7, in two bits of x-7 if x is greater than 7.